# How is the roof on this bridge town formed?

Tags: building

I recently came across this build from [Markus Rollbühler](https://www.flickr.com/photos/moriartus/51705564337/):

[image: Bridgetown]

It includes many great details and building techniques. I'm curious how the conical tower roof is formed, though:

[image: Tower roof]

It's obviously made using a number of [cheese slopes](https://rebrickable.com/parts/54200/slope-30-1-x-1-x-23-cheese-slope/):

[image: cheese slope]

How are they all attached?

Comment: Something cheesy is going on with that roof.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

At first, I assumed that this was a clever technique using something flexible like a net or tubing. After a bit of digging, I found a [similar tower roof](https://www.flickr.com/photos/moriartus/36025371241/in/photostream/) on a different build by the same person:

[image: Similar build]

Someone had asked about the roof technique on that build, and Markus included a photo looking up the inside of the roof structure:

[image: Tower interior]

The build makes use of round elements of different sizes with elements of an appropriate length clipped around them like spokes. This is a great technique that delivers a nice result if you have loads of parts and patience available.

Comment: I'm not quite sure pictured technique has been actually used in build posted in question. Maybe a variation of it, but not exactly the one mentioned here. Picture clearly shows two cheese slopes are kept together with single robot arm while original build has each cheese slope placed individually.

Comment: @Alex That's a great point. I assume the the inside structure is similar, but the build from the question only uses one cheese slope per spoke.

Comment: You can attach the cheese slopes to the light grey "light saber grips", leaving out the darker grey robot arms.

Comment: This exact building technique, while possible, wouldn't be used by LEGO, since wheels could be stressing out parts and connection looks to be rather weak (wheel doesn't have bar connections). TLG, however have recently announced Sunflowers (40524) set, which is using similar approach, but with "legal" technique, as seen [Brickset](https://brickset.com/article/67634/review-40524-sunflowers) review.